# Distinguishing between rvalue Views and rvalue Containers

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, type-traits, c++14

I am writing some container or iterable-based algorithms.  Basically, I operate on objects that support `for( : )` style iteration (I rarely use `for( : )` directly, but follow how it looks up the `begin` and `end` iterators).

In the `std` library, most every iterable objects are containers.  They both own their data, and they let you look at it.

When an algorithm takes a container by rvalue reference, this implies that the contents of the container are also free to be taken from.  As an example, if I write `concatinate` which takes two `vector`s and returns a third, if both `vector`s are `move`d, we will want to reuse the first `vector` then use `move_iterator`s to take the data out of the second `vector` for efficiencies sake.

However, with C++1y's `string_view` and types that are similar in conception, we have iterable objects that are not containers, but rather views into containers.  Semantically, I believe views behave like pointers, so their "by-value" duplication is duplication of the view into the container, not the data they refer to.  If I take a `string_view` style view by rvalue reference, that doesn't mean it owns the contents: moving from the contents is not justified, no more than moving the contents of a pointer just because the pointer itself is an rvalue.

Meanwhile, containers follow value semantics, and moving their contents because they are an rvalue is valid.

For `string_view` this isn't a problem, but I have written more generic `view` classes, such as `contiguous_range_view`, which lets you act on subsets of a `vector` or `array` or `arr[]` as if it was a non-mutable sized buffer.

These views do not always treat their contents as `const`, but they do not *own* their contents.  So the view being an rvalue does not imply that their contents are rvalues!

My algorithms like `concatinate` run into problems here.  Views are nearly indistinguishable from containers, and rvalue containers are valid to be moved-from, while rvalue views are not.  And a function that returns a view by value is a good pattern, as views are semantically pointer-types.

I'm looking for a nice, clean way to distinguish between containers and views.  Is there a plan to distinguish `string_view` in C++1y through some property or tag that I could emulate or hook into now?  If not, is there a good pattern?

If I manage to block views from being moved-from accidentally, I will still need to be able to move from them sometimes, so I'll need a way to mark a view as being a move-from candidate other than being an rvalue reference.  I suspect a `make_move_range` function might solve that problem (that takes an iterable range, and applies `std::make_move_iterator` to `begin` and `end`).

Comment: How do you append into a view?

Comment: As you say, it is a faulty assumption that because a class rvalue has member functions that return iterators, that those iterators will refer to variables that are movable.  The relationship of ownership must be asserted in order to make that leap.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I think Yakk really means "concatenate" rather than "append".

Comment: @Casey yep, clarified language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: I think the most visible difference between `Container` and `View` concepts is that containers have `insert` and `erase` operations, and views don't. I'd try to use that fact to write a type trait to detect `Container`-ness. Specifically, I think all standard containers have an `void erase(iterator)` member.

Option 2: Containers manage memory, views do not. Standard containers all have a member `typedef allocator_type`.

Notably, neither of these observations holds true for `std::array` or builtin arrays.

Comment: A traits class `is_owning_container` that looks for `allocator_type`, and specializes on `std::array<T,N>` and `T[N]`, seems to be working reasonably well.  A fancier version would ensure that `allocator_type` at least looks like an allocator, and double-check with `void erase(iterator)`, or just specialize on every `std` container and be done with it....

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to distinguish between `std::string` and `std::string_view`, I would use something like this :

```
template <
class String = std::string, 
class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<decltype(std::declval<String>().substr(0))>::value>::type // Check if the type has the substr member
>
constexpr bool is_view(const String& str = String())
{
    return std::is_nothrow_constructible<String, std::string>::value;
}
```

As containers, should manage memory, their constructors are not nothrow, whereas containers view seem to have nothrow constructors.

EDIT:
Thanks to the Casey answer I think that this kind of metafunction to detect whether a type is a view or a container (assuming that views are not trivial objects but arrays are) would work.

```
template <class Type>
constexpr bool is_view()
{
    return (!std::is_trivial<Type>::value) 
        && (!std::is_constructible<Type, 
             std::allocator<typename Type::value_type>>::value);
}
```

Comment: If `Type` is `std:vector<int, MyAllocator<int>>`, it is not constructible from `std::allocator<int>`. I think you are overcomplicating what should be a simple SFINAE test of whether `Type` has a nested type `allocator_type`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this general pattern would help:

```
struct Container
{
    CopyIterator begin() &;
    CopyIterator end() &;
    MoveIterator begin() &&;
    MoveIterator end() &&;
};

struct View
{
    CopyIterator begin();
    CopyIterator end();
};
```

Comment: This would require changing the standard containers, which is beyond my scope.  :)

Comment: @Yakk: Well you could add a type trait that identifies whether a class is a container or a view, and then only transfer move semantics in the appropriate case - effectively doing the above as a wrapper.